# allowing anonymous uploads to the Windows 7 FTP server

Tags: iis, windows-7, ftp

I am having some difficulty using the Windows 7 FTP server. I would like to be able to connect anonymously and upload files to the FTP root directory, but I get access denied error messages when I try.

I have turned on the windows features *InternetInformationServices*->*FTP Server*->*FTP Service* and *Internet Information Services*->*Web Management Tools*->*IIS Management Console*

In the *Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager* under *Default FTP Site* I have *Allow All Users Read,Write* permissions.

I have enabled *Anonymous Authentication* and *Basic Authentication*.

I have temporarily disabled the Windows 7 firewall.

I am able to use FTP from a remote PC to view a directory listing of the FTP root directory. But, I cannot upload data to it. When I try, I get this error:

```
ftp> put somefile.txt
200 PORT command successful.
550 Access is denied.
```

The PC hosting the FTP server is on a domain. I do not have domain admin rights.

What settings do I need to change to allow anonymous uploads to the FTP server?

Thanks,
PaulH

Comment: How about the file system permissions. Does the user running the FTP service have write access to the destination folder? (This is separate from the IIS permissions)

Comment: Yes. The user has local admin privilege and can write to that folder.

Comment: use the port 22 while connecting to the FTP server

Comment: I had the same problem - and this solution worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue on Windows 7, but I solved it by allowing the "Users" group `write` and `modify` permissions on the file system folder which was the FTP root.

1. Find the ftp root in your file system
2. Right-click > Properties > Security
3. Edit the settings for the "Users" group to include `write` and `modify` permissions

I think this is required because the `anonymous` FTP user will assume the privileges of the `IUSR_...` Windows account - which isn't necessarily the same user as the one running the FTP service?

Hope this helps.

Comment: I ended up switching to FileZilla, but this answer looks good. :)

Comment: +1: This answer fixed the same problem for me!

Answer (score 2):

**IUSR** is the actual local user account (with modify permissions) IIS uses to put files.  So, all you need to do is add IUSR to the ftproot folder (and all items within).